# Why is Unfocused event triggered while typing on an Entry?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms application I would like to perform a validation on an `Entry` element when the user focus it out. Using `Completed` event only works when the user taps "enter" on the keyboard. I tried to use `Unfocused` but this event triggers while the user is typing on the Entry element and I really do not understand why.

How could I perform a piece of code only when an Entry element is unfocused?

I've 10 `ViewCell` elements like this one:

```
<ViewCell >
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="13, 5" >
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="1">
                                <Label Text="Matricola" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" ></Label>
                                <Entry x:Name="matricola" Text="{Binding Paziente.MatricolaPaziente, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Completed="Entry_Completed" Unfocused="Entry_Completed" ></Entry>
                                <Label Text="{Binding RegistrationValidator.MatricolaError, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" TextColor="IndianRed"></Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
```

Code behind:

```
private async void Entry_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e){
// Some code here
}
```

Moreover the event triggers with unexpected random senders (other `Entry` elements, always with `e.IsFocused == false`)

Comment: Can you show your code of the unfocused event ?

Comment: I am also using the Unfocused event in Xamarin.Forms for the same purpose. On iOS, I don't see this event being fired when the user types. Havent checked Android yet

Comment: @MouseOnMars I'm testing on Android.

Comment: @MarcelCallo I think it doesn't matter since I'm experiencing the same behaviour even if I leave the event Handler completely empty.

Comment: How do you hook up your event handler? Can you show us some code?

Comment: @MouseOnMars Sure. I just added some code.

Comment: Use the TextChanged event for [input validation in Entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/validation#triggering-validation-when-properties-change)

Comment: @Benl but TextChanged triggers for each key tap...right?

Comment: I just edited the question adding more info.

Answer (score 2):

The `Entry` focus issue inside `ListView` seems to occur (on second row of the `ListView` and onwards) on Android (8.1 and 9.0) (Xamarin.Forms 4.5.0.356).

See also "[Entry focus issue inside ListView](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1600)".

As a workaround, use [`CollectionView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/) (without `ViewCell` in `ItemTemplate`).

Sample without Entry focus issue:

```
<CollectionView>
  <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
      <x:String>First</x:String>
      <x:String>Second</x:String>
    </x:Array>
  </CollectionView.ItemsSource>
  <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Entry Text="collectionview" Focused="Entry_Unfocused" Unfocused="Entry_Unfocused" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Sample with Entry focus issue in `ListView` on Android (8.1 and 9.0):

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.ItemsSource>
    <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
      <x:String>First</x:String>
      <x:String>Second</x:String>
    </x:Array>
  </ListView.ItemsSource>
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ViewCell>
        <Entry Text="listview" Focused="Entry_Unfocused" Unfocused="Entry_Unfocused" />
      </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Codebehind for observing the focus events:

```
void Entry_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Entry_Unfocused:{e.IsFocused}:");
}

void Entry_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Entry_Focused:{e.IsFocused}:");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried with a sample forms like this

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="15">
        <Label Text="Text" FontSize="Medium" />
        <Entry Text="{Binding Item.Text}" d:Text="Item name" FontSize="Small" Unfocused="Entry_Unfocused" Completed="Entry_Completed" />
        <Label Text="Description" FontSize="Medium" />
        <Editor Text="{Binding Item.Description}" d:Text="Item description" FontSize="Small" Margin="0" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

And in the code behind:

```
 private void Entry_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        var txt = ((Entry)sender).Text;

        DisplayAlert("Info", $"Value of text after entry lost focus : {txt} ", "OK");
    }

    private void Entry_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var txt = ((Entry)sender).Text; 

        DisplayAlert("Info", $"Value when Enter Key is tapped : {txt} ", "OK");
    }
```

Everything works fine! While looking into your code again, it seems your are in listview. Maybe the problem might come from there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Unfocused event gets triggered regardless of focus or unfocus, but the `FocusEventArgs` on the event should have a bool called `IsFocused` which should show whether or not the Entry is still focused. Have you tried checking that? It looks like you Unfocused Event Handler just uses a generic EventArgs when it could be using the more specific `FocusEventArgs`

Comment: e.IsFocused is always = false.

Answer (score 0):

Unfocused event is raised whenever the Entry loses focus. I make a simple code to test and verify.

Xaml:

```
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding list}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Entry Text="{Binding Name}" Unfocused="Entry_Unfocused" />
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Code:

```
public partial class EntryPage : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> list { get; set; }
    public EntryPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        list = new ObservableCollection<Person>()
        {
            new Person (){ Name="A"},
            new Person (){ Name="B"}
        };

        this.BindingContext = this;
    }

    private void Entry_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

[image]